# SuiteScript TypeError: Cannot read property "firstname" from undefined

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a problem that's not making any sense to me. I have created a custom search and I am using the results from that search to addSelectOptions to a select field I have added.

However when trying to simply access a value within a nested object I am getting the error message: TypeError: Cannot read property "firstname" from undefined.

Here is the code:

```
var sfPlayersSearch = search
      .create({
        id: 'customsearch_pm_sf_players_search',
        title: 'SF Players Search',
        type: search.Type.EMPLOYEE,
        columns: [
          'entityid',
          'firstname',
          'lastname',
          'custentity_pm_ws_sf_player',
        ],
        filters: ['custentity_pm_ws_sf_player', 'is', 'true'],
      })
      .run()
      .getRange(0, 100);


    log.debug({ title: 'SF Players', details: sfPlayersSearch });

    var player1ProxyField = form.addField({
      id: 'custpage_pm_ws_sf_player_1_proxy',
      label: 'Player 1 Proxy',
      type: ui.FieldType.SELECT,
    });

    var player2ProxyField = form.addField({
      id: 'custpage_pm_ws_sf_player_2_proxy',
      label: 'Player 2 Proxy',
      type: ui.FieldType.SELECT,
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < sfPlayersSearch.length; i++) {
      log.debug({title: 'Result', details: sfPlayersSearch[i].values.firstname});
      player1ProxyField.addSelectOption({ value: sfPlayersSearch[i], text: sfPlayersSearch[i].id });
    }
```

JSON Object:

```
[
  [
    {
      "recordType": "employee",
      "id": "8",
      "values": {
        "entityid": "Artur X",
        "firstname": "Artur",
        "lastname": "X",
        "custentity_pm_ws_sf_player": true
      }
    },
    {
      "recordType": "employee",
      "id": "50",
      "values": {
        "entityid": "Darryl X",
        "firstname": "Darryl",
        "lastname": "X",
        "custentity_pm_ws_sf_player": true
      }
    },
    {
      "recordType": "employee",
      "id": "1983",
      "values": {
        "entityid": "Douglas X",
        "firstname": "Douglas",
        "lastname": "X",
        "custentity_pm_ws_sf_player": true
      }
    },
    {
      "recordType": "employee",
      "id": "86477",
      "values": {
        "entityid": "Paul X",
        "firstname": "Paul",
        "lastname": "X",
        "custentity_pm_ws_sf_player": true
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated. I have tried doing .values || {}.firstname and this returns no error, but also no result.

Answer (score 0):

`Search.run().getRange()` returns an array of `Result` objects.  These are what you are iterating through in your `for` block.  The `Result` object does not include `values` but rather includes methods for access the values `getValue()`) and text (`getText()`) of each result.

Change

```
log.debug({title: 'Result', details: sfPlayersSearch[i].values.firstname});.
```

to

```
log.debug({title: 'Result', details: sfPlayersSearch[i].getValue('firstname')});
```

Comment: further to @Krypton 's answer the value parameter expects a string not an object. 

`player1ProxyField.addSelectOption({ value: sfPlayersSearch[i], text: sfPlayersSearch[i].id });` should likely be `player1ProxyField.addSelectOption({ value: sfPlayersSearch[i].id, text: sfPlayersSearch[i].getValue({name:'firstname'}) +' '+ sfPlayersSearch[i].getValue({name:'lastname'}) });`

Answer (score 0):

While @krypton 's answer is correct for what you are doing you may find it useful to use Netsuite's JSONified version of search objects like what you see in your log.

If you were writing this as a library file where you might want to work in a Map/Reduce you can normalize the search result like

```js
.getRange(0, 100)
.map(function(sr){ 
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sr));
});
```

Now your original code for `values.firstname` would work.

Fun fact. If you are using SS 2.1 you can use `let`', `const`, and arrow functions:

```js
const players = search.create()...
.getRange(0, 100)
.map(sr=>(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sr)));
```